# Electron - prevent webview from accessing local files

Tags: webview, electron

I have an Electron app that loads 3rd party code from local files installed on user's computer into a `<webview>` tag. Currently the webview is able to load any local file via absolute paths (`file://...`) or parent references (`../../file.ext`).

For security reason, I want to limit the webview's local files access to only the files inside a specific directory (where the html file is), and prevent it from accessing anything outside. Is it possible to do it in Electron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself: If you reference the html in webview's `src` attribute with `file://...` protocol, the webview will be able to access all the local files.

So the solution is instead of pointing directly to the html with `file://...` protocol, you should run a local web server that serves only the static files that you want the webview to have access to. When the webview's `src` is loaded using `http(s)://...`, Electron will automatically treat it like a normal web page, blocking access to all local files. Problem solved.